# Adding Image to TableViewCell with Button Click in DetailVC Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

My tableViewCell takes the user to a detail viewController. There is a favorite button on the detail viewController that allows the user to add the entry as a favorite. When the button is clicked, I want a heart to be placed in the entry's corresponding tableViewCell.

I haven't figured out how to make this happen. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does your `favorite button` shows on every cell?. (is a part of cell). OR favorite button is only one (is a part of Viewcontroller)?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz the favorite button is only part of the viewController. However, an imageView is in every cell which is where I want the heart to show.

Comment: yes, you can use delegate or notification to send a value to previous view controller. And when that happens, just update your datasource(Array) with new value and reload the table view.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions to achieve what you want,

1. Using delegate:

   - You can create protocol in detail view controller, and register delete of that protocol in list VC.
     So when click on favorite button in detail VC, you can call list VC with selected index of particular item and update cell in detail VC.
     You can take reference from this URL: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm
2. Using NSNotificationCenter (As given answer above):

   - Register for notification in list VC and post notification from detail VC with favorite button clicked (Register with userinfo)

As per me delegate will be good solution if you just want to update info in 1 class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great use for NSNotificationCenter.

Have the cell listen for a "didMakeFavorite" notification. Have your detail controller post the notification when the favorite button is pressed. The cell and detail view remain completely decoupled; and if there are other objects that need to know about the event, they too can add themselves as observers.

Include something like an item ID in the notification's `userInfo`, so the cell can check whether this notification is for its item, or another cell's (in which case this cell should do nothing more).

Answer (score 0):

I had done same thing by changing object of list viewModel/Model other option are notification and delegation can also work.

```
 // make change in backScreen's CategoryListing Page from where user come here and tapped on wishlist
            if let categoryViewModel = CategoryManager.shared.categoryViewModel, let product = (categoryViewModel.products.filter { $0.id == self.product.id })[safe: 0]{
                product.isWishListed.value = isWishListed
            }
```